# Search - IQueryable Linq

Tags: c#, linq, search

I'm making a function to search for members and I want to add a Where to my searchResults variable. However it might need to be an IQueryable before I could do so.

This is what I want to accomplish:

```
var searchResults = listMembers.DataSource = members.getAllMembers().OrderByDescending(x => x.createdDate).Select(x => new
    {
        x.ID,
        x.memberNumber,
        x.name,
        x.email,
        x.birthDate,
        hasPayed = Helper.renderBoolImage(x.hasPayed, true),
        isConfirmed = Helper.renderBoolImage(x.isConfirmed, true),
        isExportedToExcel = Helper.renderBoolImage(x.isExportedToExcel, true)
    });

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.name))
    {
        searchResults = searchResults.Where(x => x.name.ToLower().Equals(enc(search.name.ToLower())));
    }
```

This line doesn't compile though, since it cannot resolve the Where:

```
searchResults = searchResults.Where(x => x.name.ToLower().Equals(enc(search.name.ToLower())));
```

Comment: For a case insensitive equality check, use `a.Equals(b, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` (or another culture if appropriate).  If you must convert the string yourself, you should use `ToUpperInvariant` rather than `ToLower`.  See [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
var searchResults = listMembers.DataSource = members.getAllMembers()...
```

You should use:

```
var searchResults = members.getAllMembers()...;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search.name))
{
    searchResults = searchResults.Where(...);
}

listMembers.DataSource = searchResults;
```

Currently the type of `searchResults` is the same as the type of `listMembers.DataSource`, *not* the type of `members.getAllMembers...`

In general I'd advise against multiple assignments like your original code (`x = y = z`) - it makes the code more confusing, as you've found...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would you suggest I should perform this operation then - since you don't like the multiple assignment. The search object contains 6 more values I need to check for, so it's not only the name.

Comment: @KLIM8D: It's not clear what you mean. Do you *want* to set the `DataSource` property to the unfiltered values? It's not clear why you want to use multiple assignment.

Comment: At the end of this method I want to set the `DataSource` property to the filtered values (searchResults). The variable `search` is an inner class which contains 6 variables - all of them nullable. It's not certain I need to search for everything in this search object - since some of them can be null.
So what I got in mind was 6 almost similar if statements as the one in the topic.

Comment: @KLIM8D: It sounds like you want the code that I've written, but with another 5 "if" statements in there...

Comment: Yes that is how I planned to code it, but since you wrote `In general I'd advise against multiple assignments like this - it makes the code more confusing, as you've found...` - I thought you might had a better way writting this code :)

Comment: @KLIM8D: I was advising against the `x = y = z` style in your original code. My suggested code doesn't have that.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file? Are you using at least .NET 3.5?